# Any forests in Europe where a group of people could survive as hunter-gatherers?

Tags: survival, forests

Are there any larger "wild" forested areas left in continental Europe, where a group of people could (in theory) sustainably live as hunter-gatherers?

Looking at maps of forested areas, I struggled to find a larger area with enough supposed wildlife where I could imagine a group of (say) 100 people could sustainably survive just hunting wild animals and picking berries. Perhaps the Carpathian mountains in Romania and Ukraine? What about Western Europe (France, Germany...): anything there that could in theory work?

**Ps:** by "large enough", I also mean large enough not to run into "regular people". I.e. is there any **wilderness** left in continental Europe, where a group of (say) 100 people could live in at least (say) 20km by 20km area of nature, without regularly being disturbed by tourists and hikers?

Comment: You are aware that there is no place in Germany that is further than ≈6.3 km away from houses? So what exactly do you mean with "not run into people? a) being get around so they won't be seen by people or b) never see other people? Also, 100 people is IMHO rather large for *one* group of hunter-gatherers: https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.0611197104 predicts roughtly 2500 km² for a terrestric hunter-gatherer population of size 100 - that would be a 50 x 50 km square or a circle with 28 km radius. That would be like taking the Kreis Ostprignitz-Ruppin (correct size, one of the Kreise with lowest...

Comment: ... population density in Germany with < 40 inhabitants/km² and then tell 999 out of every 1000 inhabitants to leave). Alpine regions do pose the difficulty here that alpine terrain won't feed many animals and thus also few hunter-gatherers. Thus, you'd need to look for otherwise uninhabited valleys.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX: surely in the middle of the Schwarzwald, you'd be more than 6.3Km away from nearest houses?

Comment: In UK there is no wild land, in the sense that it is all owned. In Scotland there are some large areas that could be called wilderness, but a group of 100 people living there would be quite against the spirit of its "freedom to roam" policy. You'd have to put up with organised excursions by other people looking for the wilderness experience too. It's been done, for a TV doc and IIR after a few months they were all gasping for TV and take-aways.

Comment: @JanStuller You'd even have to look hard to find a place with no house in a 6km radius (there's lots of small huts etc.), but without tourists? Impossible. The Schwarzwald is completely criss-crossed with hiking paths.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the responses so far: they in a way confirm my "worry" that there is no real wilderness left in central and western Europe. For a real taste of wilderness without much tourism, one would probably really have to venture to the carpathian forests of Ukraine and Romania...I can't think of any other region in Europe. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: @JanStuller: "surely in the middle of the Schwarzwald..." I'm happy to be corrected - but have a look e.g. at https://www.ioer.de/fileadmin/internet/Oeffentlichkeitsarbeit/Pressemitteilungen/PDF/20190826_aktualisiert-20190827_PM_IOER_Publ-Siedlungsdichte_Behnisch-et-al_-_Kopie.pdf Figure 2 shows few spots in the Schwarzwald that are > 1.5 km from the next house (in that study defined as building with > 10m² ground area). The remotest spots in that sense are all on (current or former) military training areas. That's also the study (went through the media a year ago) where I got the 6.3 km from.

Comment: @JanStuller: My guess would be that you'd have to look for a less well known region. Since Europe goes all the way to the Ural, the forests north of Wolga/Kama may offer some choices. Also probably less touristy than the Carpathians.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX: agreed. I am just so disappointed that in Central, Western and Southern Europe, there seems to be almost no real wilderness left. As per the other comment above, perhaps a bit in Scotland, but the land is privately owned... so the conclusion is that if someone wanted to experience wilderness survival, one would have to venture all the way to the Carpathians, Wolga / Kama Ural (not safe) etc...

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, a plane ticket to Canada will give you access to wilderness where 100 people could disappear and be virtually certain of never meeting anyone else.

Comment: @JanStuller, while not central Europe you will certainly find plenty of untouched wilderness in Scandinavia and the Baltics. Though surviving in he northern parts of those countries as hunter/gatherers will be _harsh_.

Comment: @DJClayworth: :D :D That is a gold comment :). Jokes aside, I do gotta visit the Canadian countryside!

Answer (score 1):

If this question is academic, Lapland or parts of Spain have very low density of people.  Cannot say about gathering, but hunting and fishing are subject to legal regulation, so if we keep these in mind the answer is nowhere in the world where the rule of law applies.  Indigenous communities can have special hunting rights (depending on country and legal system), but this is a different kettle of fish.  Obviously there are places where the rule of law does not apply, but said places are normally in a state of war, so I'd avoid them.